markdown-to-jsx editing overrides for nested markdown
I have defined some overrides to used for some markdown but I want to define in one of those overrides an override to the overrides haha. Something like:
<Markdown
    children={source}
    overrides={{
        h1: ({children}) => (<h2>{children}</h2>),
        CustomComponent: ({children}) => (
            <Markdown
                children={children}
                overrides={{
                    h1: ({children}) => (<h3>{children}</h3>)
                }}
            />
        )
    }}
/>

this doesn't work because the children my overrides component function receives is no longer a string. After searching a bunch and not being able to find a solution I was wondering, Is there any way to achieve this? maybe a "decompile" function to revert the children object back to markdown or something along those lines? Thank you for the help!
I tried the previous snippet on this markdown:
# title 1
<CustomComponent>
  # title 2
</CustomComponent>

and got an error instead of:
<h2>title 1</h2>
<h3>title 2</h3>

